# How to remove a block of text from a text file via command line?

Tags: command-line

I would like to ask for your help! There is a text file (target.txt) and I would like to crop some lines from it. I thought it would be a good approach to add these lines to a separate file (to_crop.txt) and write a script which parse the target.txt file for the exact content in the to_crop.txt and when it finds and crops it the result file would be overwritten back to the target.txt (make it smaller).
(Why I need this? During a command line installs script I had to append a config file with some parameter lines (#starthere command #finishere) like:

star there
command xyx,bla bla
finish here

I need to create an uninstall script which removes these lines from this config file.) I would like to use a cmd file in command prompt to do it. Thanks for your ideas in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use sed, the stream editor: [sed.](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+sed)

Comment: It seems i find a 3-line solution :)) type target.txt | findstr /V /G:to_crop.txt  > tmp.txt     copy /B /V /Y tmp.txt  target.txt
del tmp.txt
Only tiny issue is that teh new file contains line breaks

Comment: Well, there's always  Python. That'd get it done cleanly and exactly as you wanted to. Of course, you'd have to learn Python... :)